# How to align grids and margin to left and right edge equally

Tags: css

## Original

[image]

## Expected

- gird1 and grid 4 should be aligned
- gird2 and grid 5 should be aligned

[image]

## Update

I slight changed your width to **80%**

It seems not works weel.

[image]

The **blug line** length should equal to **red line** (left margin should equal to right margin)

Those grids should be centered,

but now they are seems to too close to **left**

[image]

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}    
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Post the code you are using

Comment: Thats exatly what CSS flexbox allows you do do

Comment: You want all grid elements in one row to have the same height, depending on the "highest" one per row?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.  You create your boxes in a wrapping container.  Here is a VERY simple example with hard widths (not ideal):

http://jsfiddle.net/ztpftp1p/

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    height: 80px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box">Box 3</div>
    <div class="box">Box 4</div>
    <div class="box">Box 5</div>
</div>
```

The better way would be to do it with percentages and box-sizing. I can write that up for you if needed, or you could just use a grid framework like bootstrap or foundation.

Comment: Yes, your update doesn't work because, like I said, my example is using hard widths, not percentages. If you want to change the width to 80%, you would need to change the box widths to reflect the change. My example was just demonstrating floating boxes with equal spacing. If you are expecting them to be responsive based on the container width, then that's something totally different. If you know the container width will never change, then you can get away with a simple version like I showed. Do you know what your container width will be?